# Humanity With Avian Lungs

Tags: humans, biology, avian

In mammals - and that includes us humans - the lungs make up 7% of the total body volume. This allows us to inhale oxygen and exhale carbon dioxide, thanks to the pulmonary alveoli.

But bird lungs are unrivaled. They make up 15% of the total body volume. Gas does not mix between in- and ex- halation.

If we humans have a unidirectional respiratory system like a bird's, how would it affect the following?

- Athletics
- Vocalization

Comment: As for the second part, may I recommend looking up the Syrinx?  The answer is "quite very different" because birds' syrinx is quite different from our vocal chords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Athletic performance would obviously be improved though we might sound a bit different**. Birds are able to fly for such extended periods of time because their aerobic capacity is so much higher than mammals.

Humans with continuous breath so pausing for a breath on an extended soprano high note will be a thing of the past. There won't be a distinction anymore between whistling while breathing in or breathing out since the vocal cords will be serviced by the outgoing trachea.

Comment: How would the athletics be improved?

Comment: Double volume of lungs = double oxygen intake = double speed metabolism = no more gasping or getting _out of breath_. Also, birds have a different channel for inhaling and exhaling which means the speed of inhalation would also be doubled, implying yet more oxygen intake.